# Integral in $[\epsilon,\infty]$, no anal. expr. but can approx. in $[\epsilon,x\rightarrow\epsilon]$ and $[y\rightarrow \infty,\infty]$. Best approx?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation

Say I have an integral in $[\epsilon,+\infty]$, with $\epsilon>0$, that does not allow for analytical expressions, but I can approximate its value in $[\epsilon,x]$ and in $[y,+\infty]$ for $x\rightarrow \epsilon$ (this one is $k*ln(x/\epsilon)$ with $k$ a known constant) and $y\rightarrow +\infty$ (this one is $k'e^{-y^{2}}/y^{5}$ with $k'$ a known constant). Which would be the best way to approximate it?

Answer (score 2):

Best where?  One approximation is good near $\epsilon$, another is good for very large $x$; between those extremes, one or both or neither **might** be good. It's impossible to say from this distance, but I suspect you might be better off with an approximation method that isn't based on either of those limits: perhaps one of the standard numerical integration methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah, I thought the same, but I know one can use things like taking the expression f(x) near epsilon and matching it to the one of g(x) near infinity, or making something like f(x)*(x-a)+g(x)*(x-b), those kinds of things, to approximate solutions of ODEs and stuff. I'm not an expert in asymptotics, but I see your point.